# Reset name and email for commits on GitHub without changing date

Tags: git, github, git-amend

Like so many others, I have committed to a repository with the wrong name and email.
While there are A LOT of posts and solutions on how to correct these informations and some to preserve the date, I can't find a solution that **preserves the date on GitHub**.

Based on the other posts, the best I've been able to make is the following:

"FIX"

- Set correct name: `git config --local user.name "Correct Name"`
- Set correct email: `git config --local user.email "correct@name.com"`
- Change all commits from root: `git rebase -i --committer-date-is-author-date --rebase-merges --root`
- Mark relevant commits with "edit"
- For each commit, change it's author and committer: `git commit --amend --author "Correct Name <correct@name.com>" --no-edit && git rebase --continue`
- Push the changes: `git push -f`

It preserves the date in `git log` but it's changed on GitHub.

My question is: **How do I change the username and email of my historical commits without changing the date *on GitHub*?**

### To replicate the behavior

- Make a repository on GitHub
- Clone it: `git clone <link>`
- Set wrong name: `git config --local user.name "Wrong Name"`
- Set wrong email: `git config --local user.email "wrong@name.com"`
- Make some commits

  - `echo "Hello" > fun.txt`
  - `git add fun.txt`
  - `git commit -m "Add fun.txt"`
  - `echo "World" >> fun.txt`
  - `git add fun.txt`
  - `git commit -m "Update fun.txt"`
  - `git push`
- Wait some time (enough to see that the time is changed)
- Do "FIX"
- Check that `git log` show the correct date
- Check that GitHub shows the wrong date

### Note: Inconsistent dates

While I don't need to cherry pick which commits to edit, to everyone who does: The dates can get inconsistent as you can see in the image below.
So be careful with using the above "FIX" blindly.

[image: Image showing inconsistent dates]

Comment: Look for the `git-filter-repo` project on github ; the older `git filter-branch` also has a subcommand which fixes exactly this

Comment: @LeGEC, I've now had the time to look into `git-filter-repo`. It does half of the job, which is not good enough. Yes, I've been able to change the committer and author of a commit, but the wrong profile is still shown in `contributors` and in `issues`.

Comment: @LittleHelper This is a github issue not a git issue. A solution is to rename to something else (and back if you wish) and wait a few minutes for the contributors to update.